# How to handle object does not exist of get_object in Django REST?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my Django views, I call the `get_object` method to query a record that exist to user types. There can be instances where a user would get none or empty. I call this method to several other methods such as `get`, `patch`, etc.

```
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class FooViewSet(GenericAPIView):
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            foo = Foo.objects.get(pk=pk)
            return foo
        except Foo.objects.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError('Foo Does Not Exist')
        
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        obj = self.get_object(pk)
        return Response({})
    
    def patch(self, request, pk, format=None):
        obj = self.get_object(pk)
        return Response({})
    
    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        obj = self.get_object(pk)
        return Response({})
```

I am trying to catch if the object does not exist and throw a ValidationError but I get this error instead:

```
catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

How to correctly throw an error if an object does not exist with a URL query parameter such as this implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.objects is the model [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/managers/), not the model class that has that [exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/class/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist)

try:

```
except Foo.DoesNotExist:
```